# Onmouseover соеденить с maphilight (координаты картинки)

Tags: javascript, css

Использую сервис http://www.image-maps.com. Там можно создать событие `onmouseover. Подскажите, как через это событие создать, чтобы при наведении область становилась темнее. В идеале, конечно, хотелось бы узнать как сделать еще и всплывающее окно с текстом. Структура кода получается такая

```
<img id="Image-Maps-Com-image-maps-2014-04-14-145125" src="http://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/amkibe89mh8p409q0vn8liup97_gen366.png" border="0" width="960" height="977" orgWidth="960" orgHeight="977" usemap="#image-maps-2014-04-14-145125" alt="" />

<map name="image-maps-2014-04-14-145125" id="ImageMapsCom-image-maps-2014-04-14-145125">
    <area id="33" alt="" title="" href="http://www.image-maps.com/" shape="rect" coords="429,264,484,379" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="this.style.color='red';" onmouseover="this.style.color='red';" onmouseout="this.style.color='red';" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="958,975,960,977" alt="Image Map" style="outline:none;" title="Image Map" href="http://www.image-maps.com/index.php?aff=mapped_users_0" />
    <area id="1" alt="1" title="1" href="#" shape="poly" coords="280,335,317,303,360,302,362,376,320,378" style="outline:none;" target="_self" onclick="this.style.borderWidth='1';this.style.borderStyle='dotted'" onmouseout="this.style.borderWidth='1';this.style.borderStyle='dotted'"
    />
</map>
```

Comment: http://szsi.com.ua/page/map/ - посмотрите здесь

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, вот только всплывающее окно не могу вывести, не подскажете?

Comment: @нгш, Пожалуйста, задавайте новые вопросы в новом топике.